# Removing the 3 biggest values of each column in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix like

```
mat <- matrix(sample(100,100,replace=TRUE),nr=10)
```

I would now like to remove the 3 biggest values of each column so I would then have a new matrix with 7 rows.
I tried to make vectors of each column and then remove the 3 biggest values there with

```
x1 = x[x!=max(x)]
x2 = x1[x1!=max(x1)]
x3 = x2[x2!=max(x2)]
```

and then put the vectors into a new matrix, but as my matrices sometimes have a lot of columns I'd like to find a easier way.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could loop through the columns using `apply` with `MARGIN=2`, `sort` each column and remove the three highest values with `head`

```
apply(mat, 2, FUN=function(x) head(sort(x),-3))
```

Or if we want to keep the order, use `rank` to get the numeric index, get a logical index by comparing with 1:3, negate (`!`) and subset the columns.

```
apply(mat, 2, FUN=function(x) x[!rank(-x, ties.method='first') %in% 1:3])
```